# PHP: pdo_sqlite.so (pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver)) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

PHP

```
/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I've enabled pdo, that's alright. but when it comes to pdo_sqlite I can't solve this

Comment: Can you please point me to the PHP documentation about this function `php_pdo_unregister_driver`? I haven't found it...